# Custom module creation issue

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have created a custom module for magento. I was doing one by one. Created config file and done few changes and it was working. After running the store i have made few changes to config.xml file inside etc folder like layout insertion and through the layout i have included one js file with addJs..But its not getting included in my front end.
I have tried clearing cache also.Nothing happened.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_OTP>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Custom_OTP>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customotp>
                <class>Custom_OTP_Helper</class>
            </customotp>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
          <payment>
            <rewrite>
              <cashondelivery>Custom_OTP_Block_Payment_Form_Cashondelivery</cashondelivery>
            </rewrite>
          </payment>
        </blocks>
    </global> 
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customotp>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Custom_OTP</module>
                    <frontName>customotp</frontName>
                </args>
            </customotp>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customotp>
                    <file>customotp.xml</file>
                </customotp>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

customotp.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>customotp.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Show your module config.xml and layout xml file code here

Comment: @AkhileshPatel please check the question now.

Comment: make sure your customotp.js file is exist in js folder on root. and can you post your complete code of customotp.xml file here?

Comment: I have only mentioned code inside customotp.xml

Comment: added my answer. As per your comment i think there is no layout tag in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have any syntax/format error in your XML layout file. If you have errors, Magento simply ignores it.

Another hint:
The syntax you used is to add a javascript file outside the skin path, your syntax is to add files from main `js` folder.

Make sure you are not expecting a different scenario and you are expecting to **get it from yout theme**.

If you need to add JavaScripts from your theme skin, you have to use the following syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  ...
  <default>
  ...
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/myfile.js</name>
    </action>
  ...
  </default>
  ...
</layout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have placed my js file in js/ path only

Comment: Then check you layout XML syntax, I'm pretty sure you have errors. The one you pasted is athe complete XML file or just a part of it? Becasuse if it is the complete file you are missing the "layout" tag.

Answer (score 0):

customotp.xml code should be like this

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>customotp.js</script></action>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```